# sorting students according to marks

Tags: bash, grep

I am a new Linux user and using it for about 2 weeks. I am trying to create a very simple program, but first let me explain:
I am an assistant in a office of an educational institute. Periodically, I have to make report about those students who are 1 mark short of next grade and those who are below 60 marks. For instance, my report includes following type of content:

```
1. Michael 89
2. John 79
3. Oliver 79
.
.
.
20. Sarah 39
21. Twain 47
.
.
```

Until now, I have been doing it manually by looking at huge list and writing all students one-by-one. However, now I heard that I can create a simple program in bash which can do this task for me. I know that I can use some tools like grep to filter test, like

```
[workstation24 ~] cat students_marks |grep 79
[workstation24 ~] cat students_marks |grep 89
[workstation24 ~] cat students_marks |grep 47
[workstation24 ~] cat students_marks |grep 39
.
.
.
```

I also created a simple program with following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep '69\|79\|89'
```

and it is working fine, however, I don't know that how can I tell this program to also list all those students who are below 60 marks. Please help me that what should I include in this program to list under 60 (marks) students. Regards

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to make it easier for contributors to help you find the solution, please provide an example of what your `students_marks` file looks like; this is very important in order to give you specific advice on the usage of `awk` and/or `grep`. Of course, you can (and most likely will) post an anonymized version with bogus names here ;)

Comment: Give an example of your expected output. You also don't need to use `cat`. `grep 89 student_marks` will give the same output.

Comment: Originally the result is on online portal. I use to copy/paste result in a simple test file (screenshot: https://ibb.co/QmvQsjK). I think that the output file should also be simple text file with same format as original file. Kindly check screenshot link.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick edit from Piotr, I replaced $3 with $NF which is the last field

```
awk '{if ($NF + 0 < 60 || $NF == 69 || $NF == 79 || $NF == 89)print $NF,$0}' file.txt | sort -n | cut -f2- -d' '
```

$NF is the last field in awk which is printed with print at the first field so the sort utility can sort it numerically (keep in mind that the sorting is in a ascending order which you can change to a descending order by adding an additional flag to sort which is -r) also the whole line/record/rows or whatever you call it is printed because of $0. The last piece is using cut to cut the first field/column using a space delimiter. If you remove the the last pipe which cut is using then you can see the output. That code may not be as robust as what one would expect but you can use it as a reference. I don't claim that it is perfect.

Comment: Is it necessary here to use "file.txt" as input? Can we leave it as general, so that if I use it in a script so I don't have worry about file name and can use it by: my_script < input_file.txt > output_file.txt?

Comment: I have added: awk '{if ($NF + 0 < 60 || $NF == 69 || $NF == 79 || $NF == 89)print $NF,$0}'  | sort -n | cut -f2- -d' ' --- (omitted file.txt) in a script. Now I am getting same (correct) results by using: my_script < students_list > result.

Comment: Good to know that you have same results. and yes file.txt is just an example of an arbitrary name.

Answer (score 0):

In the title you mention sorting, so let's start with this part. In GNU/Linux there is a large amount of [core utils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html), that allow you among other things to deal with files of space separated data. So you can [sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) numerically (`-n`) according to the third column (`-k 3`) with:

```
sort -n -k 3 students_marks
```

Another great tool is [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html). It reads a file line by line and executes some statements. In your case you can use:

```
awk '{ if ($3 + 0 < 60 || $3 == 69 || $3 == 79 || $3 == 89) print; }' student_marks
```

on a command line. It can't (or rather it is cumbersome) sort the result, but you can connect the output of a command to the input of another using a pipe `|`:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ if ($3 + 0 < 60 || $3 == 69 || $3 == 79 || $3 == 89) print; }' $1 |
sort -n -k 3
```

When you run the script, the last `$1` will be replaced with the argument you provide on the command line.

Comment: Yes, that's working. However, I made a mistake while sharing sample text file. As you can see that my sample text file contains marks in 3rd column, however, in original file, this is not the case, and some students have first_name and last_name, but some students have first_name, middle_name and last_name and in some cases some students have four portions in their name. In this case we cannot use -k 3 and $3. How can I overcome this difficulty?

Comment: Can you obtain the data in CSV format?

Comment: I can copy/paste the data in libre-calc and it allows me to save as csv.

Comment: The safest solution would be to mark in some way the start and end of the student's name, which in CSV is well defined. If you copy paste into LibreCalc, you'll get the same result as with `sort` and `awk`: sometimes 3 columns, sometimes more. So the only easy way out is counting from the last field as in @Jetchisel 's solution.

Comment: You both (Jetchisel and Piotr) are very expert and knowledgeable. Kindly guide me that if I want to learn to use and combine different tools (like awk, sed, cut etc) along with conditions and symbols, then do I have to learn programming or something else?

Comment: It is called _bash scripting_ and is a sort of programming. The only difference with C or similar is that all functions (proper functions or commands) take an array of strings as parameters.

Comment: Although the guidelines say to avoid to say "thanks" or +1 but I am tempted to say "Thank You" :-)